# Problems with regex matching

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm currently learning Python and I'm trying to make a small scraper but I'm running in to problems with Beautiful Soup and regex.

I am trying to match all links in a site that has the following html:

```
<td>
    <a href="/l1234/Place+Number+1">Place Number 1 </a>
</td>
<td width="100">
    California  </td>
<td>
    <a href="/l2342/Place+Number+2">Place Number 2 </a>
</td>
<td width="100">
    Florida </td>
```

I want to get all the following links : "/lxxxx/Place+Number+x"

I am using python and beautifulsoup for this:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

address = 'http://www.example.com'

html = urllib2.urlopen(address).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for tag in soup.findAll('a', id = re.compile('l[0-9]*')):
    print tag['href']
```

The regex part in the soup.findAll I found on some example code because I can't seem to get the example from the BeautifulSoup documentation to work.Without the regex part, I got all the links on the page, but I only want the "lxxx" ones

What am I doing wrong with my regex? Maybe there's a way to do this wthout regexes, but I can't seem to find a way.

Comment: where do you see id = lXXX? it's about href!

Comment: Thank you for using a html parser god created a kitten today when he saw your post.  Try matching the href not the id!

Comment: Ah yes, I was not sure about that part in the code sample I found. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest

```
for tag in soup.findAll('a', href = re.compile('^/l[0-9]+/.*$')):
    print tag['href']
```

for avoiding tags looking like but not exactly what you are look like

Comment: Awesome, that filtered out the other links the previous regex was matching. Now I just have to actually understand the regex hehe.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't you be trying to do the regex match on `href` and not `id`?

```
for tag in soup.findAll('a', href = re.compile('l[0-9]*')):
    print tag['href']
```

Comment: Ah yes I was not sure about that part in the code sample I found and the BSoup docs are not very clear about that. But it's now matching also these links:                               listado.php?mrdstartid=20&alpha=yes&l=A     (why can't I enter a newline in the reply box?? I press enter and it posts the reply!)

Comment: @user664698:  IIRC Shift-Enter will do what you want in a Comment.

Comment: @user you can't do newlines in comments, and if you change the `*` to a `+` it will require numbers after the `l` in the regex

Answer (score 1):

Apart from check href not id

```
re.compile(r'^\/l[0-9]{4}/Place\+Number\+[0-9]+')
```

match seems to assume your regex starts with "^".

```
>>> m = re.compile(r"abc")
>>> m.match("eabc")
>>> m.match("abcd")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f23192318b8>
```

So adding the \/ allows the first slash to be matched. Also I'm using {4} to match four numbers rather than * which will match zero or more numbers.

```
>>> m = re.compile(r'\/l[0-9]*')
>>> m.match("/longurl/somewhere")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f2319231850>
```

Comment: Yes, {4} is definitely better than *. You can also use \d instead of [0-9].